# airflow v1.10.1 - SSHOperator does not log the ssh command

Tags: airflow

Since we upgraded airflow from v1.8.1 to v1.10.1 the ssh command that is executed by the SSHOperator is not showing in the logs anymore. now you have the log;

```
Subtask: Output:
       <the output of your ssh command>
```

before you got the command + the output of the executed command.
Before you had the log;

```
Subtask: Running command: <your ssh command>
Subtask: Output:
       <the output of your ssh command>
```

any help on making the SSHOperator log the command again? it's good to have the command in the logs to debug your task.

Comment: indeed it appears like this [log message](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-8-test/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_execute_operator.py#L131) was removed; now it outputs `command` only [upon failure](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py#L163). I'd suggest you extend it and manually log the command. This could be a good place to use the [`pre_execute()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2802) method

Comment: @y2k-shubham thanks. extending the SSHOperator or creating a custom function that logs the command before passing it to the SSHOperator is a short term solution. I can try to create a pull request to have it back as an info/debug statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `command` parameter of the `SSHOperator` is templated, so its value is saved by Airflow on every task run for debugging purposes.

When you are viewing the task-instance's log in the Airflow UI, there is a button "Rendered Template". Click on it and you will see the value of the `command` parameter for this task instance.

[image]